# Is there a way to chain functions left-to-right in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, pipeline

Many programming languages have some means of chaining functions left-to-right, instead of inside-to-outside.

For example, in Bash:

```sh
produce some data | transform1 arg1 | transform2 arg2 | transform3 arg3
```

in F#:

```
produce some data |> transform1 arg1 |> transform2 arg2 |> transform3 arg3
```

in Kotlin:

```kotlin
produce(some, data)
    .let { transform1(it, arg1) }
    .let { transform2(it, arg2) }
    .let { transform3(it, arg3) }
```

and so on.

Does Typescript allow doing anything like this? Does it have (or allow writing) a "forward pipe" operator like `|>`? Does it have (or allow adding to all objects at once) a `.let {...}` extension function?

Comment: I guess you can achieve something similar with Promises, but not 100% what you are after. `Promise.resolve().then(transform1(arg1)).then(transform2(arg2)).then(transform3(arg3))`. The trick is then that the transform method needs to return a function which takes two arguments. eg. `function transform1(arg1){return (it) => {/*use it and arg1. "it" is "undefined" for the first part of the chain*/}})`

Answer (score 3):

There is a stage 0 proposal for EcmaScript for this pipeline operator: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

Typescript usually adopts EcmaScript features when they reach stage 3

Answer (score 1):

@HaraldGliebe has the correct answer to this, but as my comment above indicates, there is "a way" to get this to kind-of work as you expect by using promises

```js
  function transform1(arg1) {
      /* first method will have undefined as input*/
      return () => { return arg1 * 2 }
  }
  function transform2(arg2) {
      return (it) => { return it / arg2}
  }
  function transform3(arg3) {
      return (it) => { return it * arg3}
  }
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(transform1(1))
    .then(transform2(2))
    .then(transform3(3))
    .then(console.log)
```

This will send the output of the previous method into the next, but all wrapped in promises. This way is quite similar to your Kotlin example, but again, not exactly correct.

Comment: using something like [`synchronous-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/synchronous-promise) could make this do exactly what you might the OP needs.

Comment: If he's going to rely on dependencies to accomplish this, then I would recommend installing a functional programming library like `fp-ts`, which has a function called `flow` that does exactly what OP is asking for. `flow(fn1, fn2, fn3)` is equivalent to `(input) => fn3(fn2(fn1(input)))`